# How to solve the load report faild error of crystal report?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I create an windows application in visual studio 2012. In that i used crystal report. After i create an setup file. when i install the setup file in the client machine then i got an error "Load Report Failed". In this system other windows forms are properly running but only report is not open.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weHo6.png)

Comment: You need to deploy the runtime as well.

Comment: i installed the CR runtime 13_0_5.msi. But again i got this error.

Comment: i used the .net framework 4.0 in VS 2012.

Comment: Please try to find more information about the error e. g. stack trace, responsible code or something like that. `Load Report Failed` could be everything.